# Raising children in corrupted country

Tags: pre-schooler

I live in an under-military-coup-too-much-corrupted-country. There is a big gap between values and reality.

For example, policeman or military soldier should be a model for kids; They -normally- love him or -at least- feel safe while he is around. In my country, it is the inverse, stay away of them as much as you can. So the kids learn from school or TV that 'ask the policeman for help' and learn from us 'never ever talk to a policeman'.

This is just one example  of conflict between values and what happens in reality.

Question: What shall I tell me kids? The reality or the values?

Answer (score 3):

In such a country what you say must be said very cautiously in consideration of the fact that it may be repeated and repeated incorrectly.  There are much-less-serious conditions where I live so I cannot say that I can fully address nor appropriately address your concerns, but here is what I *think* may be useful.

> People in charge have a lot of things to do and what we need is not always what they can focus on, so it is best to come to your parents for help because we love you and our job is to focus on you.

Such a statement imo says nothing overtly or indirectly negative about the police force, addresses the need to inform the child of how to handle things, does not lie, and keeps things simple.

I sincerely hope that helps!